# heavy path decomposition/heavy-light decomposition

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I'm reading about the heavy path decomposition of trees and its application. I would like to know its time and space complexity. In addition, can the algorithm be implemented in distributed way? What happen with its complexity?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: This might be better suited at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know about this new page :). Thanks.